# read last sms from inbox

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, flash, air-native-extension

Is there a way to read sms from inbox using flash? I'm using flash to create an app. I've created native extension using eclipse and flash builder. The java code i used is:

```
FREObject result = null;
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String msgData = "";
if (bundle != null)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = context.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    do{
         for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
         {
             msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
         }
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
    try
    {
            result = FREObject.newObject(msgData);
    }
    catch (FREWrongThreadException e)
    {
        Log.e(DeviceInfoExtension.TAG, "ErrorRead: "+e.getMessage(), e);
    }
   }
  return result;
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes. I used following code:  FREObject result = null;
  String msgData = "";
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
  Cursor c= context.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
       // startManagingCursor(c);
        c.moveToFirst();  

        String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        //String phoneNumber = "+977xxxxxxxxxx";
        c.close();